Intersecting cycles in a torus triangulation
You can easily find a planar representation of the torus by cutting it along two non-homotopic cycles intersecting in exactly one point and you get the classic square with opposite edges identified. My goal is to do the same with a triangulation of the torus, so I want to cut along two cycles of the graph such that the sides of the resulting square are two cycles of the graph. Hence, the two cycles of the graph need to intersect in exactly one vertex. So my question is, does a pair of such cycles always exist?
The problem is, if you take any cycle as your first one, it is possible that there is no non-homotopic second cycle that intersects the first one in exactly one vertex (see example below).
We can also assume the triangulation not to have any seperating triangles.
The problem seems kind of trivial to me, yet I can't come up with an answer, nor could I find anything in the literature that coulp help. Or maybe I'm just not looking for the right terms.
At first I thought it would be enough to find a cycle that has a vertex with an edge to both sides of the cycle, but those vertices could be enclosed by other edges between vertices of the cycle, so it could not be part of the second cycle that we are looking for. Otherwise it would have been possible to take any cycle and change some edges to create such a vertex.
I also thought about drawing the graph on a square with identified edges and just moving the vertices around, but didn't think this would lead anywhere.
We could also assume there exists no such pair of cycles and find a contradiction, but I didn't find a lot to work with in this scenario.
Any help is appreciated!
Example of a cycle (red) without a crossing non homotopic cycle

“The problem is, if you take any cycle as your first one, it is possible that there is no non-homotopic second cycle that intersects the first one in exactly one vertex.” can you please give an example of this?

Your post does not seem to contain a question.

@Pranay Thanks for your answer, I added an image to my post. On the red cycle, each vertex only has edges to one side of the cycle. Hence, you can't have another cycle crossing the red one without it sharing at least one edge and thus two vertices. Of course, here you could easily choose another cycle that suits my needs, but in general it seems quite hard to adjust the cycle.

@MoisheKohan The question is: In any triangulation of the torus (without separating triangles), can you find two non-homotopic cycles that intersect in exactly one point and thus allows you to represent the graph as a square, the sides being the two cycles?
